# retrun multiple functions from dynamic query

Tags: postgresql-9.4, dynamic-sql

I need to return multiple fields from dynamic query.I am referring [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723006/return-a-select-from-a-plpgsql-function) below code what I am doing so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_names(ind_zone text,dst text,nmind text,ind text,implst text,rsvr text,n34b text,prjapr text)
RETURNS   SETOF RECORD AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
sql text;
BEGIN
sql:='select indzone,dstr,nmindar,plno,pltar,nmalt from plotboundary where indzone='|| quote_literal(ind_zone)||' AND dstr='||quote_literal(dst)||' AND nmindar='||quote_literal(nmind)||' AND indx='|| quote_literal(ind);
IF implst IS NOT NULL THEN
 sql := sql || ' AND ';
 sql := sql ||' implst = ' || quote_literal(implst);
END IF;
IF rsvr IS NOT NULL THEN
 sql := sql || ' AND ';
 sql := sql ||' rsvr = ' || quote_literal(rsvr);
END IF;
IF n34b IS NOT NULL THEN
 sql := sql || ' AND ';
 sql := sql ||' n34b = ' || quote_literal(n34b);
END IF;
IF prjapr IS NOT NULL THEN
 sql := sql || ' AND ';
 sql := sql ||' prjapr = ' || quote_literal(prjapr);
END IF;
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION get_names( text,
 text, text, text, text, text, text, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

calling function like

```
 select * from get_names('Tumakuru Zone','Tumakuru','Vasanthanarasapura 2nd Phase','Allotted','Yet to Start',null,null,null)
    AS t(indzone text,dstr text,nmindar text,plno text,pltar text,nmalt text);
```

I am getting error like

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type character varying(20) does not match expected type text in column 1.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_names(text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text) line 22 at RETURN QUERY
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `indzone` is a `varchar(20)`, not a text - you could either specify the returned record using the former, or cast `indzone` inside the function.  (This applies to the solution suggested below, too.)

### But:

As it looks like, you don't need any dynamic SQL in your function, as you never use any object (table, column, etc.) name specified on the fly.  Your query could look like

```
SELECT indzone, dstr, nmindar, plno, pltar, nmalt 
  FROM plotboundary 
 WHERE indzone = ind_zone AND [...]
   AND implst = COALESCE(_implst, implst) -- changed the `IN` parameter name to avoid confusion
   AND rsvr = COALESCE(_rsvr, rsvr)
   AND [...]
```

In certain (I'd say rare) cases, this can be less efficient than you version, but that you can find out easily on your data.  Most probably a well chosen index on the 'fix' columns (that are always compared to the incoming parameters) saves you worrying about it.

Comment: I have made mistake while returning  pltar is in double precision but I was returning as text so i was getting above error